# Вернуть ошибку из асинхронной функции с декораторм python

Tags: python, asyncio

Декоратор:

```
def timeout(func):
    async def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return await asyncio.wait_for(func(*args, **kwargs), timeout=0.25)
        except Exception:
            print('error!') <<< Печатается
            raise Exception <<< Теряется
    return _wrap
```

Код:

```
class Worker():
    def __init__(self) -> None:

        self.sem = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(10)

        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.main())


    async def main(self):
        tasks = []

        for i in range(100):
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.work(i))
            tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)


    @timeout <<< Декоратор, добавляющий таймаут
    async def work(self, i):
        await self.sem.acquire()
        print('work...')
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
        await self.sem.release()
```

Проблема: декоратор приведенный выше не возвращает ошибок, хотя код написанный в блоке `except` выполняется.

Дополнение: Кажется проблема в возвращении любых ошибок из `asyncio.gather()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А [доку](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) почитать?

> If `return_exceptions` is `False` (default), the first raised exception is immediately propagated to the task that awaits on `gather()`. Other awaitables in the aws sequence won’t be cancelled and will continue to run.

> If `return_exceptions` is `True`, exceptions are treated the same as successful results, and aggregated in the result list.

Вы задали параметр `return_exceptions=True`, в этом случае **исключения считаются успешным результатом и возвращаются в списке результатов**. Вы же результат, возвращаемый `asyncio.gather`, вообще не смотрите.

Проверим это утверждение из документации:

```
        result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
[TimeoutError(), TimeoutError(), TimeoutError(), TimeoutError(), TypeError("object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression"), TimeoutError(), TimeoutError(), ...
```

Ну там вылезли и другие ошибки, но суть в том, что всё работает как описано - при указании этого ключа исключения возвращаются в списке результатов. Если хотите, чтобы исключение выбрасывалось - не указывайте этот ключ, исключение будет выбрасываться. Но его тогда нужно будет ловить, конечно, уже в вышестоящем блоке кода.

```
        try:
            result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)
            print(result)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
```

Comment: Да, действительно глупая ошибка. Спасибо за развернутый ответ!